# Including markup in a function called from within a jquery template?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-templates

I'm using jQuery Templates from within the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin so that I have better control over how my autocomplete results are rendered. What I'd like to do is highlight the input within the result. http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/combobox.html is a good example of what I'm trying to achieve, only I'd like to use jQuery Templates to do it.

Here's what I have so far (with some of the autocomplete code abstracted out):

```
<script>
  // in this example, this.term == 'dog'
  $('#tmplProject').tmpl({text: "All About Dogs"},
    {term: this.term, highlight: function(text) {
      return text.replace(new RegExp(
                    "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                    $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) +
                    ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                  ), "<strong>$1</strong>" );
  }}) )
</script>
<script id="tmplProject" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  some other markup goes here. ${$item.highlight(name)}
</script>
```

The problem is, the `<strong>` element is getting escaped, and `All about <strong>Dog</strong>s` is showing up in the browser. but this kind of makes sense, because the template should be where the markup is, not the highlight method. So how do I separate the logic of the highlight method from the markup that gets produced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the [{{html}}](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/) tag work for you?

```
<script id="tmplProject" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  some other markup goes here. {{html $item.highlight(name) }}
</script>
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/baY3k/

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed this somewhere in the docs. This works perfectly for my example, but I'm curious how I would keep the markup in a template rather than inside the highlight method itself?

Comment: How about you split your text (using regex or split) into three objects like: prefix, text,  and suffix.  Then have your template look more like: ${prefix}<span class="matched">${text}</span>${suffix}